# Delay showing popups in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am still learning React but here is the situation - I have a popup window that shows up when the page loads. I want to delay the popup appearing by 5 seconds. Using useState worked, but when the popup is closed it shows up again after 5 seconds and it makes sense why that is happening. Based on the information I have given, is there another way to manage opening and closing of popups in react?

Here is what I have so far with useState

```
const PopupModal = ({url}) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const closeModal = () => setOpen(false);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setOpen(true)
        }, 5000)
    }, [open])
    if (!open) return null

    return (
        <Popup open={open} closeOnDocumentClick onClose={closeModal}>
            <h1>Hey Hey!</h1>
        </Popup>
    );
};

export default PopupModal;
```

Comment: why you put this if (!open) return null ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dependency array is wrong. You're saying "set the timeout anytime that `open` changes". You should have it be "set the timeout anytime that the `setOpen` function changes (which is only on the first render)"

```
const PopupModal = ({url}) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const closeModal = () => setOpen(false);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setOpen(true)
        }, 5000)
    }, [setOpen]) 
    if (!open) return null // also this line is useless, since you're using the `open` prop of the Popup component

    return (
        <Popup open={open} closeOnDocumentClick onClose={closeModal}>
            <h1>Hey Hey!</h1>
        </Popup>
    );
};

export default PopupModal;
```